# get and show number of HIV/AIDS infected people in my site from http://www.worldometers.info/

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp

i am designing of a website about aids and want to show count of HIV/AIDS infected people in world real time.
we know that **http://www.worldometers.info/** is a great resource for obtain information 
about this.
but my question is that is a way for get count of HIV/AIDS infected people from this site for example via ajax and JSON(JSONP) and show it in my site or no?
if yes , how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you read what's written on that site? It's a paid sevice to have thair info on your site. http://www.worldometers.info/licensing.php